# Unable to start the web server while setting-up Eureka Service, error: application missing the necessary class definition for the RestClient$Builder

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, netflix-eureka, service-discovery, spring-boot-starter

I am trying to setup a basic Eureka Service Discovery but, while implementing the same I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.project.discoveryserver.DiscoveryServerApplication.main(DiscoveryServerApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat': org/springframework/web/client/RestClient$Builder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:218) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/RestClient$Builder
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRestClientBuilderBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadBalancerRestClientBuilderBeanPostProcessor.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-commons-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$Builder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Moreover, while mentioning the port number and other config required for the eureka server in the application.properties file, it is showing the warning that the mentioned properties are not being used.
Also attaching the pom.xml, application.properties and Main class for reference:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>microservices-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761
```

DiscoveryServerApplication class:

```
package com.project.discoveryserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class  DiscoveryServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

to resolve the same I have tried to ensure the presence of the required JAR by:

- Checking iy my build configuration includes the spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency.
- Verified that the JARs for WebClient are properly downloaded and included in your project's classpath.

Attaching the dependency tree for spring-boot-starter-webflux for your reference:

```
\- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO]    |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.94.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:6.0.11:compile
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing things from Spring Boot 3.1 and 3.2 (like Spring Cloud 2023.0.0 is only compatible with 3.2, and `RestClient` also only works with Spring Boot 3.2). The problem however is that we can't help you because you left out a lot of information. For example, your `pom.xml` has no notion of which Spring Boot version you use and your dependency tree doesn't incldue the Eureka-library. So for now I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @g00glen00b, the above tree is only for my Discovery Server Class, since I thought there were some dependencies missing to enable the Eureka Server. But the above service is under the umbrella of another micro service, in which I was using Spring Boot 3.1.2, but now is running after changing the version to 3.2.0. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after changing the Spring Boot version in my parent microservice's `pom.xml`, attaching the `pom.xml` for your reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>product_service</module>
        <module>order_service</module>
        <module>inventory_service</module>
        <module>discovery-server</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Cloud version for Spring Boot 3.1.5 is 2021.0.5
In your pom Add :

```
 <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
```

or search for Spring Boot version match with Spring cloud version on Internet ,this will solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>product_service</module>
        <module>order_service</module>
        <module>inventory_service</module>
        <module>discovery-server</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```